# My settings app is incomplete

Tags: 19.04

Basically I have installed the gnome settings app using

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

But where I expected all the settings, my app only shows some of the possible settings as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: What desktop are you using?  This looks like what happened to me when I installed this app with an LXDE desktop.  If you are using the default desktop, you would not have to install this.

Comment: @OrganicMarble how do I know which desktop I am using? I think it's X11, but how do I confirm it?

Comment: Did you install stock Ubuntu?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I must sound like a total noob, but what is a "Stock Ubuntu"

Comment: No, I'm not being clear, my apologies. If you just downloaded and installed Ubuntu, you would by default get the "Gnome desktop" which should have had this setting package already installed. I'm asking if you did something different.

Comment: @Organic Marble, I had this installed by default when I installed Ubuntu a few months back, then the settings were gone for some strange reason. I re-installed it and all the settings were there but now that I wanted to change some settings, it appears like some of the settings are excluded.

Comment: OK, thanks. So this is a case of "it used to work but now it doesn't".

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it is not a bug, but a slight mishap from my part, as it turns out, I was inside the "Devices" tab of settings, which then only showed few of the settings. I could easily go back to the original settings by settings by clicking on the <-- icon on the top left of the screen.